# Create bash alias that takes unknown number of arguments

Tags: bash

I want to create a bash profile that does something like:

```
$ga file_1 file_2 file_3 ... file_n
```

where `ga` would be `git add`.

This is a bit contrived of an example, but the issue is with a changing number of arguments.

How can I create an alias or function to do this in Bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliases are not handling arguments themselves. Instead think of themselves as *macros* in some programming languages. When the shell encounter a command which is an alias, it simply replaces that alias with the definition.

So for example, if you have

```
alias ga='git add'
```

Then when Bash sees the command `ga` is simply replaces it with `git add`. All arguments you have written are passed as they are to `git add`.

If you need to do some processing of the arguments, or reorder or replace or remove them, you can't use aliases. Instead you have to use *functions*:

```
function ga() {
    # Call git add with reordered arguments
    git add $1 $3 $2
}
```

For more information please [read the Bash manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html). There are also many tutorials all over the Internet if you just search a little.

Comment: Then how do I use the function?

Comment: @AlanH Functions are used just like commands or aliases. In the case of the `ga` function defined in my answer, that how you use it: `ga`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if your example was maybe too simple, because in that case you don't need to make your alias "aware" of the changing number of arguments.. 
alias ga='git add'
and then
ga file1 file2 file3
will actually work as you want. The shell will simply pass all the arguments to the alias.

Comment: Would the same work with `git commit -m "my_message"` if I just has an alias of `gc` and did `gc "my_message"`

Comment: @AlanH For that you need an alias such as `alias gc='git commit -m'`.